# Find conflicting Javascript with browser developer tools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, drupal, developer-tools

I'm trying to debug a CMS-backed website (Drupal 7). It is displaying some problems due to conflicting Javascript. For a fraction of a second, the site components are fine, and then *SNAP*, they're broken. It must brake as soon as the conflicting resource loads.

Using Chrome's developer tools (*or Safari, Firefox... even IE's*), is there a way to load the page, one Javascript resource at a time? This way I can see *exactly* which resource loads when the page issues appear.

(I'm also open to better ways of debugging this kind of thing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Pause on exceptions** feature of DevTools, in *Sources* Tab, it is the hexagonal pause button at the far right.